# Views Slideshow Galleria in drupal 7

Tags: views, 7, javascript

I used the combination of Views + Views Slideshow + Views Slideshow: Galleria. And got the slider as I need which was given in the http://galleria.io/themes/classic/ . But I also need to show the title field below respective thumbnail image and the second thing is, onclicking the thumbnail image should show the title on the larger image too.

I have added both the Image and Title field but the galleria shows only the images not the Title.What steps I have to take for these result? Could anyone help me in this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Similar to what I've done here http://www.cnngo.com/hong-kong/life/guide-years-mid-autumn-festivities-315693 and here http://www.cnngo.com/explorations/life/cnngo-air/cnngo-tv-secret-side-taipei-041193 ???

Comment: The slider in http://www.cnngo.com/hong-kong/life/guide-years-mid-autumn-festivities-315693 is nice but I wanna display the text on the large sliding image.And wanna to set the large image as background image and the slider process should work. Any ideas?

Comment: I have Galleria installed but did you check your Views settings why the Title is not showing?

Comment: Yes I checked the views settings.I have added the Title and body field under the fields.But the images alone are displaying in the gallery.